# How to get html5 and knockout support in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html, knockout.js

I have created a mvc3 project without selecting the HTML markup semantic support checkbox. now i am trying to use knockout js in my project. Since knockout only work with html5 so i choose html5 debugging mode from visual studio. But ko.applyBinding is not working.please help..

Comment: post the code, the problem seems to be somewhere else

Comment: can you add complete code of yours

Answer (score 0):

May Your problem is binding the ko.

**Try to bind your viewModel for a particular div id like below code.It may solve your prob**

**Html**

```
<div id="container_id">
...
<div>
```

**Script:-**

```
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel(), document.getElementById('container_id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For HTML 5 you need to change your HTML structure like below way.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
// Body content will come here.
</body>
</html>
```